# Netsuite Email Merge Error (SSS_MERGER_ERROR_OCCURRED)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm creating a Scheduled SuiteScript in Netsuite that uses the 1.0 version of the API. The goal is to have the script run once per day to send our first time customers an email with their name (or company name) and other pre-formatted content using a Scriptable Email Template.

Once it is up and running, we are planning to extend it with additional functionality, but this is the base that we would like to have running before adding additional code.

The error message is:

SSS_MERGER_ERROR_OCCURRED - Merger error occurred: Unexpected error encountered during merging.

Everything goes smooth up until actually using .merge(). I've added the code below:

```
function thankyouletter() {

var searchresults = nlapiSearchRecord(null, 'customsearch127'); // minus: , filters

if (searchresults == null) {
response.write('Var searchresults is null.');
return;
} else {
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'START - Found search results', 'Starting iteration');

for (var i = 0; searchresults != null && i < searchresults.length; i++) {
  var searchresult = searchresults[i];
  var searchCols = searchresult.getAllColumns();
  var internalid = searchresult.getId(); // Will be used after testing is finished

  var emailMerger = nlapiCreateEmailMerger(38);
  emailMerger.setEntity('customer', 24886); // Set for Testing
  var mergeResult = emailMerger.merge(); // Fails and errors here
  var emailSubject = mergeResult.getSubject();
  var emailBody = mergeResult.getBody();

  nlapiSendEmail(nlapiGetUser(), customerid, emailSubject, emailBody, null, null, null, null);
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Merge Troubleshooting', 'Just after SendEmail');

}
}
var usageRemaining = context.getRemainingUsage();
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'usage left => ' + usageRemaining);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Script Finished.', 'Mission Complete');
}
```

I've removed some of the nlapiLogExecution lines for readability. If anything is confusing or additional info is needed, please let me know and I'll add/fix it.

I've dug through piles of Netsuite's documentation, SuiteAnswers, and web searches trying to find the solution, but the error message is pretty vague.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found that the Freemarker Template had a syntax error, and that was causing the error.